# Distribute overflow text equally on both sides of element

Tags: html, css, text, overflow, figure

I got the following problem:
I got a `<figure>`, whose `<figcaption>` may overflow the `<figure>`. You can see that in the fiddle below:

```css
body{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
figure{
  width:300px;
  height:500px;
}
img{
  width:100%;
}
figcaption{
  position:relative;
  top:-50px;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:3em;
  white-space:nowrap;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:bold;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<figure>
<img src="https://www.zooroyal.de/magazin/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Golden-Retriever-760x560.jpg">
<figcaption>Golden Retriever</figcaption>
</figure>
```

What I want to achieve is that the text is still centered within the `<figure>`, no matter if the text is wider than the figure or not.

I can't think of a possible solution. Does anyone know a way to achieve that? Without the use of JavaScript please.

Answer (score 6):

Use these styles:

```
    figcaption {
        position:relative;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        width: auto;
    }
```

Hope this is what you want to achieve.

Comment: Perfect and so simple. Thanks alot.

Comment: @TobiasGlaus Always happy to help.

Comment: Note that if you want to just put these styles on any div, you have to add display:inline-block, or else it will translateX based on its parent's size instead of its own.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve this:

```
body{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
figure{
  text-align:center;
}
img{
  width:300px;

}
figcaption{
  position:relative;
  top:-50px;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:3em;
  white-space:nowrap;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:bold;
  width:100%;
}

<figure>
<img src="https://www.zooroyal.de/magazin/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Golden-Retriever-760x560.jpg">
<figcaption>Golden Retriever</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want..

```css
body{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
figure{
  width:300px;
  height:500px;
}
img{
  width:100%;
}
figcaption{
  position:relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: auto;
    font-size:2em;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<figure>
<img src="https://www.zooroyal.de/magazin/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Golden-Retriever-760x560.jpg">
<figcaption>Golden Retriever</figcaption>
</figure>
```